# Rapidjson findmember

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I have a JSON string like this:

```
{"callCommand":{"command":"car","floor":"2","landing":"front"}}
```

Now, I would like to check if there is a name called `command` and get the value. Is it possible? My code is as follow, but it doesn't work.

```
const char json[] = "{\"callCommand\":{\"command\":\"car\",\"floor\":\"2\",\"landing\":\"front\"}}";

rapidjson::Value::ConstMemberIterator itr = d.FindMember("command");

if (itr != d.MemberEnd())
    printf("command = %s\n", d["callCommand"]["command"].GetString());
```

Answer (score 3):

You are searching for "command" at the top level of the document:

```
d.FindMember("command");
```

When you should be searching for it inside "callCommand":

```
d["callCommand"].FindMember("command");
```

Also, after you search with FindMember, you should use the iterator instead of searching again using operator[].  Something like:

```
// assuming that "callCommand" exists
rapidjson::Value& callCommand = d["callCommand"];
rapidjson::Value::ConstMemberIterator itr = callCommand.FindMember("command");

// assuming "command" is a String value
if (itr != callCommand.MemberEnd())
    printf("command = %s\n", itr->value.GetString());
```

Comment: This solution only work if you know how the json is constructed. FindMember does not work in a recursive way unfortunately

Answer (score -4):

You can use rapidjson's `HasMember` function, as follow:

```
Document doc;
doc.Parse(json);
doc.HasMember("command");//true or false
```

Comment: as per their own documentation, FindMember should be used. https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html